# High-pitched noise from tower during DSKCHK on SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, bsod

I've had a string of computer issues beginning last night including data corruption on Windows 10 leading to failure to boot, and the data corruption issues seem to have persisted despite a clean install on the same hard drive.

Since my clean install, I've run into 3-4 MEMORY_MANAGEMENT BSoDs and one KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE. Applications such as Chrome tend to crash or break often in my computer's current state, and many other programs run into issues downloading files or crashing abruptly. I ran Windows Memory Diagnostics tool to check my RAM, which came back as fine. I've run SFW and DISM multiple times, but SFW detects but cannot fix all of the issues, and DISM fails to correct issues, while I cannot find an install.wim file to point DISM to.

Today I ran a DSKCHK on C:, an SSD, and it froze at 11%, proceeding to make a loud noise from the tower for 10-15 minutes before making a high-pitched beep once and restarting. After the restart, there was an intermittent whirring noise, similar to a metal fan that was off-balance.

All of this leads me to believe it is a hardware issue, but I don't know for sure if it is my SSD, as when I looked up similar issues, many people point out that since there are no moving parts, an SSD would not make noises like I was hearing.

I am just a college student so I don't have money to just replace parts until I get it right, I wanted to get opinions or find ways to verify which component if any is acting up before I get a replacement. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Today I ran a DSKCHK on C:, an SSD, and it froze at 11%, proceeding to make a loud noise from the tower for 10-15 minutes before making a high-pitched beep once and restarting. After the restart, there was an intermittent whirring noise, similar to a metal fan that was off-balance.

- When you boot your system, you should have an option to press F2 or similar to get into a firmware menu.  If you don't see a prompt on the screen, put the make and model of your system into Google with the words " access BIOS menu" or " access firmware menu."

  - Once you get into the firmware you might be able to access a log facility that tells you why it shut down.

It's unlikely a failing SSD would make any noise.

The hardware I would suspect, in order of suspicion, is:

- Broken CPU fan - CPU is overheating and causing shutdown
- Broken power supply fan or issue with power supply.
- You have something metal on the motherboard like a screw causing a short.
- Bad RAM.

If you have 2 sticks or more of RAM, you can kinda-sorta test the RAM by running it with one stick - if problems go away with only 1 stick in there, then your issue was the other stick of RAM.

Comment: I'll take apart the tower tomorrow and inspect the motherboard, my CPU temperatures seem reasonable as far as I can tell, usually ~40C. Having just restarted with a few devices unplugged, I managed to get a game installed that was previously throwing errors. I'd be amazed if a driver was causing issues like that, but it's possible...